# How to solve $\int \frac{\ln{(x^4 + x^2)}}{x^2} \mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> $$\int \frac{\ln{(x^4 + x^2)}}{x^2} \mathrm{d}x$$

Can't solve this integral. I have been sitting over it for already an hour and still can't find an obvious solution.

Please help.

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts. 
You are more likely to receive positive/constructive feedback that way.  
Formatting your post helps too.
Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Not an answer, but this is not "solving." This is "computing."

Comment: u = x^2. I think that should be a pretty big hint

Comment: Using integration by parts (differentiate $\ln$) and partial fractions is one solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int\frac{\ln(x^2+x^4)}{x^2}dx=2\int\frac{\ln{x}}{x^2}dx+\int\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x^2}dx=2I_1+I_2$$
$I_1=\int\ln{x}(-x^{-1})'dx=-\frac{\ln{x}}{x}+\int\frac{1}{x^2}dx=-\frac{\ln{x}}{x}-\frac{1}{x}+C$.

$I_2=\int\ln(1+x^2)(-x^{-1})'dx=-\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x}+2\int\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=2\arctan(x)-\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x}+C$

Comment: A Hint would have been enough i guess